# Chaining calls when using Future in Swift similar to PromiseKit

Tags: swift, combine

Below there are three functions. The first one is the function that I need to refactor. Basically what I'm hoping for is something similar what can be achieved using Promise Kit but in this case using Swifts combine framework.

The second function `loginWithFacebook()` returns a `AuthCredential`.
This `AuthCredential` needs to be passed on to the last functions which returns a type `Future<UserProfileCompact, Error>` which is a similar return type to the main function (1st function).

My question is is there a way to achieve this in a Swifty way, similar to Promise Kit doing this operation: `return loginWithFacebook().then {loginWithFirebase(:_)}`

```
    // Call site is a View Model 
    // Main Function that needs to be refactored
    func loginwithFacebook() -> Future<UserProfileCompact, Error> {
        //This returs a Future Firebase Credential
        loginWithFacebook()
        //The above credential needs to be passed to this method and this returns a type Future<UserProfileCompact, Error> 
        loginWithFirebase(<#T##credentials: AuthCredential##AuthCredential#>)
    }
    
    private func loginWithFacebook() -> Future<AuthCredential,Error> {
        return Future { [weak self] promise in
            self?.loginManager.logIn(permissions: ["public_profile","email"], from: UIViewController()) { (loginResult, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    promise(.failure(error))
                } else if loginResult?.isCancelled ?? false {
                    //fatalError()
                }
                else if let authToken = loginResult?.token?.tokenString {
                    let credentials = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(withAccessToken: authToken)
                    
                    promise(.success(credentials))
                }
                else{
                    fatalError()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func loginWithFirebase(_ credentials: AuthCredential) -> Future<UserProfileCompact, Error> {
        return Future { promise in
            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credentials) { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    //Crashlytics.crashlytics().record(error: error)
                    promise(.failure(error))
                }
                else if let user = result?.user {
                    //Crashlytics.crashlytics().setUserID(user.uid)
                    let profile = UserProfileCompactMapper.map(firebaseUser: user)
                    promise(.success(profile))
                }
                else {
                    fatalError()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `.flatMap` operator, which takes a value from upstream and produces a publisher. This would look something like below.

Note, that it's also better to return a type-erased `AnyPublisher` at the function boundary, instead of the specific publisher used inside the function

```
func loginwithFacebook() -> AnyPublisher<UserProfileCompact, Error> {
   loginWithFacebook().flatMap { authCredential in
      loginWithFirebase(authCredential)
   }
   .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. It worked for me. Could you please give me some details with regards to "it's also better to return a type-erased AnyPublisher at the function boundary, instead of the specific publisher used inside the function"
Does this mean I don't expose the Future<SomeObject,Error> in the API layer and just use AnyPublisher<SomeObject,Error>?

Comment: @MinonWeerasinghe, yes, exactly, which doesn't unnecessarily expose the internal implementation at the api boundary

Comment: what to do in iOS 13 where flatMap is not available?